# Meta keywords- Use words or phrases?

Tags: html, meta-tags, keyword

I know the relevance of meta keywords is little to none, but my client wants them.  Moreover, they gave me a list of key phrases.  Should I be inserting key phrases separated by commas, even if they repeat certain key words, or should I be including each key word exactly once, and not use phrases at all?

```
<meta name="keywords" content="big red cars, small blue cars, medium yellow cars">
```

OR

```
<meta name="keywords" content="cars, big, small, red, yellow, blue">
```

Comment: belongs on webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: @bpeterson76- ugh you're right my bad.  How do I transfer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the complete phrases.

Otherwise, when exact phrases are used for search, your customer will not be happy with you.

Comment: @Oded- OK- so I take it there's no penalty, per se, for repeating keywords?

Comment: @Yarin - As far as I know, there isn't. It's common practice.